# Weakly dependent central limit theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, st.statistics, asymptotics, limit-theorems

Say I have $N$ random variables $X_1,\cdots,X_i,\cdots,X_N$, with zero mean and finite variance. $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent iif $|i-j|>m$, and positively correlated otherwise (say the covariance is of $\mathcal{O}(1)$). It is well-known that the sums of $N$ of these random variables are distributed as a normal distribution as $N \rightarrow \infty$, if $m$ is a finite number of $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

My question is, what if $m=\sqrt{aN}$, and we take a sum of $\sqrt{aN}$ of these random variables, randomly selected from the sequence $X_1,\cdots,X_i,\cdots,X_N$. Would the sum become a normal distribution? Each time we take a sum, we resample $\sqrt{aN}$ random variables and take a sum of them.

My intuition says yes. The reason is if we randomly sample $\sqrt{aN}$ variables from the original sequence of length $N$ (and $m=\sqrt{aN}$), the expected value of the number of variables sampled from any given window of consecutive $\sqrt{aN}$ variables is $a$, based on the following calculation:

$$\text{number of samples}\times\text{probability of sampling from a given window}=\sqrt{aN} \frac{\sqrt{aN}}{N} = a$$

Now it is as if we are taking a sum of $\sqrt{aN}$ random variables that are independent if $|i-j|>a$, so the conventional '$m$-dependent CLT' still holds since our $a$ is of $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Is this intuition correct? How do I prove/disprove this more rigorously?

Comment: Did you have in mind that these all have the same variance? Or at least that their variances remain bounded as $N\to\infty\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Not the same variance, but yes bounded.

Comment: The "well-known" claim in your first paragraph is not true in such generality: Consider e.g. $X_1=X$, $X_2=X_3=\cdots=0$, where $P(X=\pm1)=1/2$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Should I specify that $0<Var[X_i]<\infty$ to make my claim true?

Comment: That would not be enough.

Comment: @IosifPinelis What if I say the sequence of $X_i$ is stationary, in which case, I assume the variance is all the same?

Comment: Even then, consider the $1$-independent sequence $(X_n-X_{n+1})_{n=1}^\infty$, where the $X_n$'s are iid Rademacher random variables.

Comment: @IosifPinelis In the example of 1-dependent sequence, I believe the CLT should hold. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Because of the telescoping effect: $\sum_{n=1}^N(X_n-X_{n+1})=X_1-X_{N+1}$, which is not asymptotically normal if the $X_n$'s are iid Rademacher.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Aha, that's an interesting counter-example. How come the large body of central limit theorem papers on m-dependent sequences never address this?

Comment: All known to me papers on such subjects address this, usually by "shamelessly" requiring that the variance of the cumulative sums go to $\infty$, possibly at a required minimum speed.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I just realized the example 1-dependent sequence does not meet the requirement that the covariance should be positive. I think the CLT holds with the requirement I have listed so far, for the finite m case at least.

Comment: Oh, I did forget about the positive-covariance condition. Then the stationarity, together with a finite variance $>0$, should suffice.

Comment: @CWC Great post! Do you mind to point out a reference to "It is well-known that the sums are distributed as a normal distribution"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Say we have a stationary process, but we observe samples at random times $\{t_n\}$ which itself is a stochastic point process (e.g. Poisson process). The resulting sample is also a stationary process ([Ref](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.851.9334&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

I assume that if the original sequence is m-dependent ($m=\mathcal{O(1)}$), the resulting autocovariance function (for the sampled sequence) decays fast enough that CLT holds for the sum of the sampled sequence.

Comment: The Ref link is dead. Can you please update it?

Comment: "A central limit theorem for m-dependent random variables" by S Orey is a good reference.